# How to send TX in the same block with emitted event in ethers.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I am listening to a specific contract on the blockchain and when a certain event occurs on the contract, I send a TX. In the best case my TX is mined in the next block of the specific event that I am using as my trigger.

In blockchain explorer I see some addresses whose TX's are mined in the exact same block as their trigger events.

My question is **how can I send a TX to be mined in the same block as the emitted contract event that I am using as my trigger?**

I am currently using ethers.js as follows

```
filter = {address: "0x...."}   // Contract address that I am listening to

// Start listening
provider.on(filter,  async (_event) => {

// Do something with _event when a TX is emitted

// Sign a raw TX if certain criteria is met
    await send_tx(tx_data, gasPrice, gasLimit)
})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @treckstar I edited my question now. Is it clear enough? If not please tell me which part so that I can try to clarify further.

Comment: From what I understand, if the event is emitted it means the block has already been mined so you won't be able to send the transaction in the same block.